# Formatting a help menu with spaces

Tags: python, python-2.7, format

I'm creating a help menu for an interactive shell, what I need is for it to output the list in a formatted way, this program already uses argparse, when no flag is given the user is redirected to a command line interface for the script (terminal). I want the user to be able to see the help menu in a formatted way:

```
TOOL_LIST = {
    "-s": ["(Run a SQLi vulnerability scan on a URL)", "sqli"],
    "-x": ["(Run a cross site scripting scan on a URL)", "xss"],
    "-p": ["(Run a Port scan on a URL or given host)", "port"],
    "-h": ["(Attempt to crack a given hash)", "crack"],
    "-v": ["(Verify the algorithm used for a given hash)", "verify"],
    "-d": ["(Do a dork check to verify if your dork is good)", "dork"],
    "-f": ["(Find usable proxies)", "proxy"],
    "-hh": ["(Produce a help menu with basic descriptions)", "help"]
}

def help_menu():
    """
    Specs: Produce a help menu with basic descriptions
    Usage: run menu
    """
    print("Command  Secondary-Command  Descriptor")
    primary_spacer = ""
    descrip_spacer = ""
    secondary_spacer = ""
    for key in TOOL_LIST.iterkeys():
        if len(key) == 3:
            primary_spacer = " " * 2
            secondary_spacer = " " * 10
            descrip_spacer = " " * len(TOOL_LIST[key][1])
        else:
            primary_spacer = " " * 2
            secondary_spacer = " " * 11
            descrip_spacer = " " * len(TOOL_LIST[key][1])

        print("{}{}{}{}{}{}".format(
            primary_spacer, key, secondary_spacer,
            TOOL_LIST[key][1], descrip_spacer, TOOL_LIST[key][0]
        ))
```

As of right now it outputs like this:

```
Command  Secondary-Command  Descriptor
  -d           dork    (Do a dork check to verify if your dork is good)
  -f           proxy     (Find usable proxies)
  -v           verify      (Verify the algorithm used for a given hash)
  -p           port    (Run a Port scan on a URL or given host)
  -s           sqli    (Run a SQLi vulnerability scan on a URL)
  -hh          help    (Produce a help menu with basic descriptions)
  -x           xss   (Run a cross site scripting scan on a URL)
  -h           crack     (Attempt to crack a given hash)
```

How can I tell python to format the output for the menu, to look something like this:

```
Command  Secondary-Command  Descriptor
  -d           dork         (Do a dork check to verify if your dork is good)
  -f           proxy        (Find usable proxies)
  -v           verify       (Verify the algorithm used for a given hash)
  -p           port         (Run a Port scan on a URL or given host)
  -s           sqli         (Run a SQLi vulnerability scan on a URL)
  -hh          help         (Produce a help menu with basic descriptions)
  -x           xss          (Run a cross site scripting scan on a URL)
  -h           crack        (Attempt to crack a given hash)
```

Comment: May I ask why you (seem to, at least) are reinventing the wheel? use `argparse`. You'll get a formatted help menu for free.

Comment: @DeepSpace it's for an interactive shell inside of the script, when the user fails to pass a flag the program will launch the shell in place of the flag, which will allow the user to run commands from the shell. (Much like how metasploit works)

Comment: @hashcode55 I already did man

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would do the job -

Replace your `descript_spacer` (at both places) with :

```
descrip_spacer =  " " * (13 - len(TOOL_LIST[key][1]))
```

I have chosen 13 because it looks exactly like what you wanted. You probably want to make it a top level variable.

Output -

```
Command  Secondary-Command  Descriptor
  -d           dork         (Do a dork check to verify if your dork is good)
  -f           proxy        (Find usable proxies)
  -v           verify       (Verify the algorithm used for a given hash)
  -p           port         (Run a Port scan on a URL or given host)
  -s           sqli         (Run a SQLi vulnerability scan on a URL)
  -hh          help         (Produce a help menu with basic descriptions)
  -x           xss          (Run a cross site scripting scan on a URL)
  -h           crack        (Attempt to crack a given hash)
```

Comment: Awesome, why does it always seem like 13 works for everything? Lol, thank you!

Comment: @secxit yeah and people say 13 is unlucky, look what it did there.